# create.json.jbuilder not returning object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jbuilder

```
def create
    @practice = Practice.new(practice_params)

    if @practice.save && @practice.start
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to practice_learnings_path(@practice) && return }
        format.json
      end
    else
      redirect_to practices_path
    end
  end

//create.json.jbuilder
json.practice @practice
```

Comment: Vivek, Welcome to Stackoverflow :) Please explain your problem. Just showing your code is not the right way to ask a question. Please have a check on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new view file for this `create` action i.e. `create.json.jbuilder` under `views/pratices`. Write your code there to return the json.

E.g.:

```
# app/views/practices/create.json.jbuilder

json.practise do
  json.attr1 @practice.attr1
  json.attr2 @practice.attr2
  json.attr3 @practice.attr3
end
```

Refer to `jbuilder` gem doc for [more information](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder#jbuilder) on this